# switch windows with command tilde when running multiple emacs clients connected to multiple daemons on OS X

Tags: macos, emacs

I use multiple emacs guy clients connected to multiple emacs daemons.
I want to to be able to switch through all emacs windows when pressing c repeatedly.

Is this possible?

(I'm using OS X)

Comment: What happens when you command tilde, like you mentioned in the title?

Comment: command  tilde does nothing right now. i have three daemons. i have one gui client window per each daemon.

Comment: i too would like to be able to do this. one partial work-around is to use `C-x b` to switch buffers, and if the buffer you select is open in the other window, it'll bring up the other window.